# Save Models to ObservableCollection through UserControl + ICommand

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I would like to save ItemModels in ObersvableCollection via UserControl that is opened with Window + ICommand.

My problem is that if I close the Window and open it again the OC will be empty. I think I know why (I suppose because of I create always a new OC)  but I don't know how I can absolve this corner.

The addition of the item to the OC is proper.
As I checked some references regarding the MVVM pattern almost in all cases the OC is implemented in the ViewModel.

Hopefully you have some suggestions for this question. I am a quite new in WPF notedly in MVVM so please forgive me if this is a lama question!
Thank you for the help in advance!

This is how I try to open the UC+Window via ICommand:

```
public void OpenAddItemWindow(Window win, UserControl uc)
    {
        win.Name = "OpenedWindow";
        win.Owner = Window.GetWindow(System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow);
        win.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;

        // Add the usercontrol to the window
        win.Content = uc;
        win.ShowDialog();
    }
```

This is how I try to implement the OC in ViewModel

```
public ItemViewModel()
    {
        ListOfItems = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();
        OpenAddItemWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenAddItemWindow);
        CreateItemCommand = new RelayCommand(CreateItem);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ItemModel> _listOfItems;
    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> ListOfItems { get { return _listOfItems; } set { _listOfItems = value; OnPropertyChanged("ListOfItems"); } }
```

Comment: You already have OpenAddItemWindow method, so maybe you can return from it with data from your child window's viewmodel?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately I could not absolve on the suggested way. Instead of that I figured out that I implement the OC with the following form in the MainWindow and then I can point to this collection:   
'(((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).ListOfItems'
With this I have to just add the new Item to this and it will hold the items after the closing of window as well. I am sure there is a better way but I hope it is not so wrong...